# How do I pass a fortran pointer to a subroutine?

Tags: pointers, attributes, fortran

Because of some reason, I need to pass a Fortran pointer to a subroutine. The subroutine is inside a module and the main program uses this module to ensure explicit interface.

My question is, what attribute should I specify on the dummy argument of the subroutine in order to receive the passed-in pointer?

I tried the code below.

```
module aaa

contains

integer*4 function print_ptr_arr_1( ptr )

    implicit none

    integer*4, intent(in), pointer :: ptr(:)

    print *, 'as pointer'
    print *, size(ptr)
    print '(10i3)', ptr
    print *

end function print_ptr_arr_1

integer*4 function print_ptr_arr_2( ptr )

    implicit none

    integer*4, intent(in), target :: ptr(:)

    print *, 'as target'
    print *, size(ptr)
    print '(10i3)', ptr
    print *

end function print_ptr_arr_2

integer*4 function print_ptr_arr_3( ptr )

    implicit none

    integer*4, intent(in) :: ptr(:)

    print *, 'as assumed shape array'
    print *, size(ptr)
    print '(10i3)', ptr
    print *

end function print_ptr_arr_3

end module aaa
```

and

```
program main

    use aaa

    implicit none

    integer*4 :: i1, ierr
    integer*4, target  :: arr(10)
    integer*4, pointer :: ptr_arr(:)

    do i1 = 1, 10
        arr(i1) = i1
    end do

    ptr_arr => arr

    ierr = print_ptr_arr_1( ptr_arr )
    ierr = print_ptr_arr_2( ptr_arr )
    ierr = print_ptr_arr_3( ptr_arr )

    nullify( ptr_arr )

end program main
```

Three subroutines in module aaa show correct outputs as below.

```
sj2734@sonaram:~/work/practice/fortran_pointer$ ./a.out 
 as pointer
          10
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

 as target
          10
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

 as assumed shape array
          10
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

sj2734@sonaram:~/work/practice/fortran_pointer$
```

What is correct and what are not? Or, are these all correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you're going to use what you're passing to the function. Do you need it to be a pointer? Then give it the `pointer` attribute. Do you need to point to it with another pointer in the function? Then, give it the `target` attribute. The dummy argument will take on whatever attributes you give it.

If you declare it as a `pointer` then you can use it as a pointer and allocate/point to new things within the function.

If you declare it as a `target` then other pointers within the function could point to it, but you wouldn't be able to point to a `target` with it since it's not a pointer.

If you just want to treat it as an array then you can just declare it as an assumed-size array and treat it like a regular array, but again you won't be able to use it in the same way as if it had the `pointer` or `target` attribute.

So they're all right, in a way. It depends on context. However, unless you really need it to be a pointer or target for a specific reason, and you're just treating it as an array then you're best off declaring it to be an assumed-size-array to avoid potential memory issues.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped a lot.